# customizing infobox with getInnerHtml

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Does anyone have some experience with the infobox of the google maps api V3.

[InfoBox](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/infobox/1.1.5/docs/reference.html)

The property content can take both plain html and or text in HTML Dom mode. 
So I figured I'm building my own infowindow in plain html like this

```
 function getInnerHtml( name, contract, detailLink)
    {
    var innerHtml = '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">' + 
                            '<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="nl">'+ 
                            '<head>'+  '<title>Framed</title>' + '<style>' +
                            '.infoLayer img {  border: none; }' + 
                            '.infoLayer { height: 83px; overflow: hidden; display: inline-block; min-width: 205px;' +
                            '.infoLayer .content { background: url(img/bg-info-layer.png) repeat-x 0 0; height: 49px; margin: 0; padding: 10px 0; overflow: hidden; float: left;' +
                            '.infoLayer .bgLeft {  background: url(img/bg-info-layer-left.png) no-repeat left top; height: 69px; width: 11px; float: left; }' + 
                            '.infoLayer a, .infoLayer a:active,  .infoLayer a:visited { color: #fff; text-decoration: none;  } }' +
                            '.infoLayer h3 {  margin: 0; padding: 0 10px 0 0; font-size: 16px;  font-weight: bold; }' +
                            '.infoLayer .bgRight { float: left; width: 31px; }' +
                            '.infoLayer .bgRight img { display: block;  overflow: hidden; }' +
                            '.infoLayer .content p {  margin: 0;  padding: 0 10px 0 0;  font-size: 12px;' +
                            '.infoLayer .bottom {  clear: both;  height: 14px;  font-size: 1px;  line-height: 1px;  text-align: center; overflow: hidden; }' +
                            ' </style>' + '</head><body>' + 
                            ' <div class="infoLayer">' + '<div class="wrapper">' + '<div class="bgLeft"></div>' + '<div class="content" style="">'  +  '<h3><a href="#">' + name + '/a></h3>' +
                            ' <p><a href="#">'+ vergoeding(contract) +'</a></p>' + '</div>' + '<div class="bgRight"><a href="#"><img src="../../Content/green_arrow.png" alt="pijl" width="31" height="69" /></a></div>' +
                            '</div>' + ' <div class="bottom"><img src="img/arrow-info-layer-bottom.png" alt="" width="29" height="14"></div>' + ' </div>' + '</body>' + '</html>';
    return innerHtml;

}



   function boxText(name, contract, vestigingID)
    {
        var detailLink =  getBaseUrl() + "/Details/" + vestigingID;
        var boxText = document.createElement("html");
           boxText.innerHTML = getInnerHtml(name, contact, detailLink);

        return boxText;
    }

 function infoboxOptions(boxText)
    {
     var Options = {
             content: boxText
            ,disableAutoPan: false
            ,maxWidth: 0
            ,pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-140, 0)
            ,zIndex: null
            ,infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1)
            ,isHidden: false
            ,pane: "floatPane"
            ,enableEventPropagation: false,
            alignBottom: false            
        };
        return Options;
    }
```

and I will get a customized infowindow. 
However this fails, I'm getting an infowindow with the wrong stuff. 
I'm I missing something here.
Also I like my infobox(window) to be on top , but I must be overlooking the property any ideas here?

I could really use some help.

Comment: You are creating '`<html>`' (`document.createElement('html')`) node and adding the other '`<html>`' ( within `getInnerHtml` function) inside it !

Comment: So I should just leave that one out ( my html tag ) , mmm ok I'll try it , thanks for your answer

Comment: I think , you were trying to wrap all your info contents inside '`iframe`' .

Comment: It's strange because I've tested it with small pieces of html and then it worked , so I guess my styling is not picking up.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out my styling is indeed doing something funky. So I decided to just use all the properties in the html tags.